# row_number() always return 1 since the source table has only one row

Tags: postgresql, postgis, row-number

Let's consider this minimal example:

```
SELECT row_number() over() as GID, 
       unnest(myarray)     as letter
FROM 
(
    SELECT string_to_array('a,b,b', ',') as myarray
) AS T
```

Now since the table `T` contains only one element, the `row_number()` function always return `1` even if 3 rows are returned.

So I get:

```
GID   letter
1     "a"
1     "b"
1     "b"
```

Instead of

```
GID   letter
1     "a"
2     "b"
3     "b"
```

How can it be fixed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `unnest` clause right around the `string_to_array` call, so that `T` has multiple rows already:

```
SELECT row_number() over() as GID, myarray as letter
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(string_to_array('a,b,c', ',')) as myarray
) AS T
```

Also I would recommend using [`WITH ORDINALITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) instead of `row_number()` to get indexed array elements:

```
SELECT gid, letter
FROM UNNEST(string_to_array('a,b,c', ',')) WITH ORDINALITY AS T(gid, letter)
```

This also works if you want to keep the array-returning select expression

```
SELECT gid, letter
FROM UNNEST(
  (SELECT string_to_array('a,b,c', ',') as myarray)
) WITH ORDINALITY AS T(letter, gid)
```

or use a lateral query:

```
SELECT gid, letter
FROM
  (SELECT string_to_array('a,b,c', ',') as myarray) AS T,
  UNNEST(T.myarray) WITH ORDINALITY AS U(letter, gid)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the example before your edit, try the following query:

```
SELECT 
 row_number() OVER () AS gid, ST_AsText(geom)
FROM (SELECT 
        st_makepixel(
          ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((2580000 1182000,2581000 1182000,2581000 1183000,2580000 1183000,2580000 1182000))',2056),200.0,50) AS geom) j

 gid |                                         st_astext                                          
-----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1 | POLYGON((2580000 1182000,2580200 1182000,2580200 1182200,2580000 1182200,2580000 1182000))
   2 | POLYGON((2580200 1182000,2580400 1182000,2580400 1182200,2580200 1182200,2580200 1182000))
   3 | POLYGON((2580400 1182000,2580600 1182000,2580600 1182200,2580400 1182200,2580400 1182000))
   4 | POLYGON((2580600 1182000,2580800 1182000,2580800 1182200,2580600 1182200,2580600 1182000))
   5 | POLYGON((2580800 1182000,2581000 1182000,2581000 1182200,2580800 1182200,2580800 1182000))
   6 | POLYGON((2580000 1182200,2580200 1182200,2580200 1182400,2580000 1182400,2580000 1182200))
   7 | POLYGON((2580200 1182200,2580400 1182200,2580400 1182400,2580200 1182400,2580200 1182200))
   8 | POLYGON((2580400 1182200,2580600 1182200,2580600 1182400,2580400 1182400,2580400 1182200))
   9 | POLYGON((2580600 1182200,2580800 1182200,2580800 1182400,2580600 1182400,2580600 1182200))
  10 | POLYGON((2580800 1182200,2581000 1182200,2581000 1182400,2580800 1182400,2580800 1182200))
  11 | POLYGON((2580000 1182400,2580200 1182400,2580200 1182600,2580000 1182600,2580000 1182400))
  12 | POLYGON((2580200 1182400,2580400 1182400,2580400 1182600,2580200 1182600,2580200 1182400))
  13 | POLYGON((2580400 1182400,2580600 1182400,2580600 1182600,2580400 1182600,2580400 1182400))
  14 | POLYGON((2580600 1182400,2580800 1182400,2580800 1182600,2580600 1182600,2580600 1182400))
  15 | POLYGON((2580800 1182400,2581000 1182400,2581000 1182600,2580800 1182600,2580800 1182400))
  16 | POLYGON((2580000 1182600,2580200 1182600,2580200 1182800,2580000 1182800,2580000 1182600))
  17 | POLYGON((2580200 1182600,2580400 1182600,2580400 1182800,2580200 1182800,2580200 1182600))
  18 | POLYGON((2580400 1182600,2580600 1182600,2580600 1182800,2580400 1182800,2580400 1182600))
  19 | POLYGON((2580600 1182600,2580800 1182600,2580800 1182800,2580600 1182800,2580600 1182600))
  20 | POLYGON((2580800 1182600,2581000 1182600,2581000 1182800,2580800 1182800,2580800 1182600))
  21 | POLYGON((2580000 1182800,2580200 1182800,2580200 1183000,2580000 1183000,2580000 1182800))
  22 | POLYGON((2580200 1182800,2580400 1182800,2580400 1183000,2580200 1183000,2580200 1182800))
  23 | POLYGON((2580400 1182800,2580600 1182800,2580600 1183000,2580400 1183000,2580400 1182800))
  24 | POLYGON((2580600 1182800,2580800 1182800,2580800 1183000,2580600 1183000,2580600 1182800))
  25 | POLYGON((2580800 1182800,2581000 1182800,2581000 1183000,2580800 1183000,2580800 1182800))
(25 Zeilen)
```

Comment: Ho, sorry for editing the question too early. And thank's for the answer !